# Conditional Statements with the @artsy/fresnel Framework

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm using the [@artsy/fresnel](https://blog.logrocket.com/build-responsive-components-gatsby-artsy-fresnel/) npm package to build a responsive React application.

Here's my code

```
<Media greaterThanOrEqual='computer'>
    <div style={{ padding: '20px 50px' }}>
           Some Content Goes Here                               
    </div>
</Media>

<Media lessThan='computer'>
    <div style={{ padding: '50px 100px' }}>
           Exact Same Content Goes Here                               
    </div>
</Media>
```

I've searched through the documentation, but could not find a way to set the padding of my div depending on the Media tag rendered. I want to achieve something like this

```
<div style={{ padding: (MediaIsGreaterThanComputer ? '20px 50px' : '50px 100px') }}>
    Some Content Goes Here
</div>
```

Is this doable with the @artsy/fresnel framework?

Answer (score 1):

You can do this, but you’ll need to take control over the wrapper div that gets emitted by the `Media` component (see [the note about “render-props”](https://github.com/artsy/fresnel#media)). So something like:

```
<Media greaterThanOrEqual='computer'>
  {(mediaClassNames, renderChildren) => {
    return (
      <div style={{ padding: '20px 50px' }}>
        {renderChildren ? "Some Content Goes Here" : null}
      </div>
    )
  }}
</Media>
```